# Adding Potion Effect when Item is in hand Minecraft Forge 1.16.5

Tags: java, event-handling, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So Basically I have been searching the internet for a way to add potion effects while an item is being held. I have found many results but none really seem to be working. My main issue is that when I get to the adding potion effect it throws errors because I am trying to use a non-static to access an abstract. I tried the @Overide several times but it never seems to work. I still need to register in forge as that is how it updates but adding PlayerEntity does not work when I use @SubscribeEvent

```
package blitz.weapon.weaponmod;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.client.MainWindow;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerAbilities;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.potion.EffectInstance;
import net.minecraft.potion.Effects;
import net.minecraft.util.Hand;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.common.capabilities.Capability;
import net.minecraftforge.common.capabilities.CapabilityDispatcher;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.TickEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.NoteBlockEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.RegistryObject;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.server.FMLServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod("weaponmod")
public class Weaponmod {

    // Directly reference a log4j logger.
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, "weaponmod");

    public static final RegistryObject<Item> RAINBOW_SWORD = ITEMS.register("rainbow_sword", () ->
            new Item(new Item.Properties()
                    .group(ItemGroup.COMBAT)
                    .maxStackSize(1)
                    .maxDamage(13)
            ));


    public Weaponmod() {
        // Register the setup method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::setup);
        // Register the enqueueIMC method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::enqueueIMC);
        // Register the processIMC method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::processIMC);
        // Register the doClientStuff method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::doClientStuff);



        // Register ourselves for server and other game events we are interested in
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        ITEMS.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());


    }





    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onPlayerTick(TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent event) {
        if (event.side.isServer() && event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
            ItemStack stack = event.player.getHeldItemMainhand();
            if (stack != null && stack.getItem() !=null) {
                if (stack.getItem().equals("1 rainbow_sword")) {
                    return;

                }
            }
        }
    }





    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        // some preinit code
        LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM PREINIT");
        LOGGER.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", Blocks.DIRT.getRegistryName());
    }

    private void doClientStuff(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
        // do something that can only be done on the client

        LOGGER.info("Got game settings {}", event.getMinecraftSupplier().get().gameSettings);
    }

    private void enqueueIMC(final InterModEnqueueEvent event) {
        // some example code to dispatch IMC to another mod
        InterModComms.sendTo("weaponmod", "helloworld", () -> {
            LOGGER.info("Hello world from the MDK");
            return "Hello world";
        });
    }

    private void processIMC(final InterModProcessEvent event) {
        // some example code to receive and process InterModComms from other mods
        LOGGER.info("Got IMC {}", event.getIMCStream().
                map(m -> m.getMessageSupplier().get()).
                collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    // You can use SubscribeEvent and let the Event Bus discover methods to call
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(FMLServerStartingEvent event) {
        // do something when the server starts
        LOGGER.info("HELLO from server starting");
    }

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically subscribe events on the contained class (this is subscribing to the MOD
    // Event bus for receiving Registry Events)
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onBlocksRegistry(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> blockRegistryEvent) {
            // register a new block here
            LOGGER.info("HELLO from Register Block");
        }
    }

}
```

That is my code for basically my whole mod, can anyone give me any pointers? (Sorry for any mistakes this is my first post)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the method in your Item-Class, than that will help you:
(ofcourse you can use here @OnlyIn(Dist.DEDICATED_SERVER) or in the method if(!worldIn.isRemote()) {...})

```
@Override
public void inventoryTick(ItemStack stack, World worldIn, Entity entityIn, int itemSlot, boolean isSelected) {
    if (entityIn instanceof PlayerEntity) {
        PlayerEntity player = (PlayerEntity) entityIn;
        if (player.getHeldItem(Hand.MAIN_HAND).getItem() == ModItemRegistry.TESTITEM) {
            player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.INVISIBILITY, 1000));
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to have the method in another Class, than use:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onPlayerTick(TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent event) {
    if (event.side.isServer() && event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
        ItemStack stack = Objects.requireNonNull(event.player.getHeldItem(Hand.MAIN_HAND));
        if (stack.getItem() == ModItemRegistry.TestItem) {
            event.player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.INVISIBILITY, 1000));
        }
    }
}
```